# MySQL Выборка из нескольких таблиц с группировкой по разным полям

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Есть три таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stat_money_streams_all` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `type` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `money` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `money_partner` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `money_moder` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `date` (`date`,`type`,`sID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stat_subscribes_streams_all` (
`date` date NOT NULL,
`type` int(3) NOT NULL,
`count` int(11) NOT NULL,
`sID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `date` (`date`,`type`,`sID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stat_traffic_streams_all` (
`date` date NOT NULL,
`type` int(11) NOT NULL,
`count` int(11) NOT NULL,
`uniq` int(11) NOT NULL,
`sID` int(11) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `date` (`date`,`type`,`sID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

В таблицах хранится статистика. Нужно выдернуть статистику из трех таблиц сразу за определенный период времени.

Написал следующий запрос, но он работает некорректно, помогите написать правильный запрос:

```
SELECT 
  traffic.date,
  traffic.type as tType, 
  SUM(traffic.count) as tHit,
  SUM(traffic.uniq) as tHost, 
  subscribes.type as sType,
  SUM(subscribes.count) as sCount, 
  money.type as mType,
  SUM(money.money) as money, 
  SUM(money.money_partner) as money_partner, 
  SUM(money.money_moder) as money_moder
FROM 
  stat_traffic_streams_all as traffic
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  stat_subscribes_streams_all as subscribes 
USING(date,sID)

LEFT OUTER JOIN
  stat_money_streams_all as money 
USING(date,sID) 

LEFT OUTER JOIN
  streams ON streams.id=traffic.sID 
WHERE 
  date
  BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2015-05-11 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE('2015-05-17 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') 
AND
  streams.uid='2'
GROUP BY 
  date,
  tType, 
  sType,
  mType
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Т.е. мне нужно выбрать статистику за период времени из трех разных таблиц, сгруппировав данные по дате. 
Три таблицы отвечают за хранение статистики по (конверсиям, трафику и финансам)
Нужно учесть что за определенную дату в одной таблице может быть Статистика, а в другой - нет, поэтому использую LEFT JOIN где основная таблица stat_traffic_stream_all

Comment: Приведите пример данных, которые у вас хранятся. Создайте тестовый пример на http://sqlfiddle.com По виду у вас как раз декартово произведение получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Ох-хо-хо... А что между этими 3-мя таблицами имеет уникальную связь первичного ключа? Если `sID`, то вот и создайте в разделе FROM 3 разные таблицы по принципу:

```
FROM
  ( select SID, date, sum(...)...
    from ....
    GROUP BY SID, DATE
  ) a,
  ( select SID, date, sum(...)...
    from ....
    GROUP BY SID, DATE
  ) b,
....
```

Так вы получите уже 3 таблицы с наборами данных, которвые вычисляться будут быстрее и правильнее. И их уже объединяйте конструкцией JOIN по полям *SID* и *Date*.

Я не указал JOIN во FROM, чтоб не путаться, там с синтаксисом сами разберетесь.

---

Вы ведь сами задали вопрос верно:

> статистику за период времени из трех разных таблиц, сгруппировав
>   данные по дате

Та вот и сделайте как его задали: 3 разные таблицы сгруппировать по датам, и потом уже вывести их в SELECT путем объединения конструкцией JOIN.

Comment: нет - так неправильно будет Группировка идет помимо даты, по полю TYPE из каждой таблицы, а если делать три разных запроса по очередности, то в конце будет очень длинное декартово произведение всех возможных значений.

Comment: @АлександрГрешников, Вы не правы, но это ваше дело, не прислушиваться к ответам. 

По Поводу TYPE - я лишь написал пример как выполнить запрос. Группировку делайте сами подбирая нужные поля. У вас даже описание задачи неверно относительно требования type (статистику за период времени из трех разных таблиц, сгруппировав данные по дате.), так что в доп.полях сами разберетесь.
Еще и минусует.. хех...

Comment: Спор легко решает Describe query, который поддерживается в mysql уже много времени